# Discrepancy between DXF and Shapefile Polygons

Tags: qgis, dxf

I have created a shapefile based on a dxf.

the areas are as follows:
DXF: 51216417 square metres = 5121.64 Hectares = 51.21 square Kilometres.
GIS: 50.998 square kilometres.

What could have caused this?

Running Autocad 2013 and QGIS 1.8

Comment: coordinate systems?

Comment: Kind of did think about that but as far as i am aware the two CRS should be the same.  I will double check.

Comment: Should "On the Fly Re projections" not allow it to be the same. That being said, the points as per coordinates are the same in AutoCAD and QGIS.

Comment: My apologise, this problem only appear in the 1.8 version. the 2.4 version creates the actual area correctly.